# UINavigationController skipping a pop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have 3 view controllers, one is the root, which pushes the next, which pushes the next. Each time you can go back (pop), using the normal back button that appears by default.

However when the 3rd view is visible, when the user taps the back button I need it to skip out the the 2nd view controller, and go (pop) directly to the root view controller.

How can I override the default back button behaviour? (I'd like to keep the shape of the back button, and not replace it with a square bar button)

Comment: I think you need to look at UIBarButtonItem, there are two methods that let you know when the back button is pressed.

Comment: @david like I said it won't have the arrow shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to have an object implement UINavigationControllerDelegate and enforce this behavior. You could also have a designer create the same size and shape asset and you could use this as the background for a button.
However, I'd rethink your UI if you really need to do this. It is contrary to the user's expectations of how a navigation controller should work.

Comment: Well the 2nd view controller is a login page, once they've logged in the won't need to login again. And in most cases the 2nd view controller will have been skipped automatically, only when the user first uses the application.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider a modal view controller?

Comment: In the end I used a Modal View Controller, except I had to implement it myself due to complications.